How to fulfill expectCount with confirmation() Swift Testing
I'm trying to use the expectedCount parameter in confirmation(_:expectedCount:fileID:filePath:line:column:_:) to check that a function completes, exactly, 25 times.
This is my test, is currently giving me the error

Confirmation was confirmed 0 times, but expected to be confirmed 25
times

@Test func testStreamingPrimesUpTo100ShouldBe25() async {
    
    let maximumCount = 100

    
    await confirmation("Calculate primes up to \(maximumCount)", expectedCount: 25) { primesNumber in
        PrimeCalculator.calculateStreaming(upTo: maximumCount) { _ in
            primesNumber()
        }
    }
}

I tried to add a counter variable that increases in value inside calculateStreaming's completion closure, and the check the expectedCount with primerNumber.confirm(count: variable) but then I get a EXC_BREAKPOINT error.
This test in particular always returns 25 numbers, because the functions calculates each prime up to 100.
the documentation doesn't mention much more about what to do with expectedCount
Here is my code for the PrimeCalculator
struct PrimeCalculator {

    static func calculateStreaming(upTo max: Int, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            guard max > 1 else {
                return
            }

            var sieve = [Bool](repeating: true, count: max)
            sieve[0] = false
            sieve[1] = false

            for number in 2 ..< max {
                if sieve[number] == true {
                    for multiple in stride(from: number * number, to: sieve.count, by: number) {
                        sieve[multiple] = false
                    }

                    completion(number)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And this would be the equivalent test in XCTest, here we are using expectation.expectedFulfillmentCount to check the same behaviour in Swift Testing.
Basically, I want to migrate this test to the new framework.
func testPrimesUpTo100ShouldBe25() {
    // given
    let maximumCount = 100
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Calculate primes up to \(maximumCount)")
    expectation.expectedFulfillmentCount = 25

    // when
    PrimeCalculator.calculateStreaming(upTo: maximumCount) { number in
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 3)
}


Your code needs to complete before the confirmation closure is complete.  See the full answer to your question in this article

Related

@JoakimDanielson I could transform my function to work with continuation, but I'm looking to use the Confirmation and expectedCount parameter

@Sweeper I want to understand how to make use of the expectedCount parameter

@Sweeper I'm trying to fulfill the expectedCount parameter in confirmation(). I provided the documentation on confirmation.
In the example and code I provided I always get the same result, not a minimum.  I even use the expectedFulfillmentCount which is the exact equivalent of expectCount.

My calculateStreaming function always returns the same result, not a minimum, I don't know what you meant by that. It returns each prime number up to 100. And then I'm trying to fulfill that the function executed 25 times, like it ALWAYS should with a parameter of 100.

Okay, I understand now. In any case, you need to modify PrimeCalculator to provide a way for the calling code to await the end of the prime calculations. Or, as I showed in my linked post, just do a try await Task.sleep(...) at the end.

You have to understand that confirmation is not a direct, drop-in replacement for XCTestExpectation, despite what the migration guide might make you think. There is currently no equivalent of XCTestExpectation in Swift Testing. confirmation checks the expected count when the body closure returns.
